# What are some useful data visualisation or data mining techniques to investigate horse racing forms?

Tags: data-visualization, model-selection, data-mining, games

I have a dataset of 13k horse races from four different tracks with an average of 11 runners per race.  In all, there are 26k unique runners in the data.  For each race, I know who came first, second, third, etc.

A horse's [*form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_%28horse_racing%29) is a record of significant events, including its performance in previous races.  To be specific, let's say form means a string of six digits ABCDEF, where A = finishing position six races ago or 0 if finished outside top 9, B = finishing position five races ago or 0 if finished outside top 9, etc.  And let's say a horse's form at track X means only races at that track are considered when compiling its string of six digits.

There are reasons to believe a horse's form may not transfer well between tracks because of differences in surface type and other characteristics.  What are some useful data visualisation or data mining techniques to investigate such a hypothesis?

Comment: Have you looked at the literature? Andrew Beyer, James Quinn, Steven Davidowitz and others have written technical books on handicapping. Beyer is one of the main originators of speed figures. 
Just "position at finish" is going to be very inadequate as a measure of form. There's distance, class, pace, track condition and a bunch of other factors to consider

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I appreciate that just "position at finish" is going to be very inadequate for handicapping.  What I'm trying to assess is whether I need four separate handicapping models, one for each track, and whether I need separate handicapping models for different distances.  I thought one way of going about deciding this would be to look at whether "form" (in the simplistic way I've defined it) differs across these dimensions for my dataset.  (By handicapping model, I mean to implement the Boltman-Chapman Multinomial Logit Model.)